# (De)serializing an object as an array in XStream

Tags: arrays, refactoring, xstream

I'm trying to clean up some old code by replacing some arrays that were being passed around with proper objects to improve readability and to encapsulate some behaviour.  I ran into a problem when it turned out the arrays were being run through XStream for persistence.

I need to retain the format of the serialization and the arrays in question are inside various other objects being (de)serialized through XStream.  Is there and easy way to handle this?

I'm hoping there's an Annotation I can apply or simple XStream `Converter` I can write for my new classes and be done with it, but from what I can see it would require writing `Converter`s for each of the containing classes instead.  I'm not sure as I'm not familiar with XStream.  If there isn't a easy solution I'm just going to have to give up and leave the arrays in place as I don't have the time budgeted for anything fancy or to learn the finer points of XStream.

Specifically, I have a `TileLayer` that has a member `int[] metaTileFactors` and I want to replace that with class `MetaTiling` which has members `final int x` and `final int y` and still have it serialize and deserialize to/from the same XML as before.

Comment: Could you post an example of your current XML?